# returning a char* array as string -> memory leak?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, winsock

```
std::string Client::listenForMessage()
{
    // ... receiving message size ...

    char* message = new char[messageSize];
    message[messageSize] = '\0';

    // ...
       ... recv(connectedSocket, message, messageSize, 0);
    // ...


    return message;
}
```

Actually everything seems to work fine, but I'm not sure.

Do I have to delete/free my message variable before I return it? Or does the conversion to string handle that for me?

Comment: You need to delete[] it.

Comment: Why not just `recv` directly into a `std::string`'s buffer and get rid of the need for `new[]` entirely?

Comment: Or, why not receive into a `std::vector<char>` so you want need a temporary and you won't need to explicitly delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very rarely need to manage your own dynamic arrays. The Object Oriented way to manage an array is using the `std::vector` class. It does all the creating/deleting for you.

So I would use a `std::vector` like this:

```
std::string Client::listenForMessage()
{
    // ... receiving message size ...

    // create a vector to manage the message array
    std::vector<char> message(messageSize);

    // ...
           // use data() and size() methods
       ... recv(connectedSocket, message.data(), message.size(), 0);

    // ...

    // construct the returned string from the vector data
    // The vector cleans itself up automatically
    return {message.begin(), message.end()};
}
```

Comment: This still wastes a buffer,  I would suggest either changing return type to `vector<char>`, or changing type of message to `std::string` .

Comment: @M.M I thought about using a string, but using a vector is slightly more comprehensible as you have to use (and explain) `&message[0]` with a string. The main goal here is safety.

Comment: I will use this solution with std::vector<char> because I only send a few sentences. Thanks!

Comment: @Created This approach will be just as efficient as your manually allocated dynamic array because the vector's methods are trivial and the compiler optimizes them away. If you do need more performance, if your compiler supports it, you can declare the vector `thread_local static std::vector<char> message;` and simply resize it every time the function is called: `message.resize(messageSize);`.

Comment: Now I changed the std::vector<char> to string and I resize it in the next line. For message.data() I use &message[0] to get the address of the first element. It feels more appropriate because I just send sentences (strings).

Answer (score 4):

It's a leak.

> Do I have to delete/free my message variable before I return it?

Yes.

> Or does the conversion to string handle that for me?

No, `std::string` doesn't take ownership of pointers passed to its constructor. (There's no way for it to know whether it was `new`'d or not.)

Answer (score 2):

It may cause memory leak, or it may crash when you write out-of-range.

`message[messageSize] = '\0';` is illegal out-of-range access, so remove it or change to

```
if (messageSize > 0) message[messageSize - 1] = '\0';
```

or something that you want *and valid*.

Then, to avoid memory leak, delete the string before returning, or the pointer to allocated memory will be lost.

```
std::string ret = message;
delete[] message;
return ret;
```

Passing data read from `recv()` in this way without checking is not a good idea because it might not be a null-terminated string.